# How to convert the comma separated string or /n separated string into list in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am entering the String either by comma separated or by clicking on enter key .. 
What i want to do is , i have separate the string with either , or /n separated with respective to input.. 
How to do it  . Can anyone help me out to solve this problem

My approach :

```
var str = $("#textValue").val(); { "hel,asda,asdasd,asdasd" }
var array = new Array();
array = emailString.split(',');
```

The above is the case when user gives input with comma separated. We dont know whether the user gives either comma separated or not.He may click on enter and give inputs. whats the solution on that scenario.
Please help me out to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the comma based split gave only one element, try a new line split :

```
var str = $("#textValue").val();
var array = new Array();    
array = emailString.split(',');
if (array.length == 1) {
    array = emailString.split('\n');
}
```

Comment: if i use both comma and \n ,?

Comment: Then Pravin Tukadiya's solution is best, use this before your split : array = emailString.replace("\n",","); :

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you.

`array = emailString.replace("\n",",");
array = emailString.split(',');`

it will replace all \n with , if user input ',' than it spit using ','.